# Design patterns to handle scenarios where there is no response from the user

Tags: design-patterns, messages

Most design patterns (used on desktop applications) for communication or passing information to users are based on the assumption that there is some response or reply from the recipient of the message or notification. However, there are common cases where this might not be the case, especially if the contact details are out of date or the person is deliberately ignoring the message.

Are there specific design patterns that deal with no responses from the recipient of the communication? For example, if a message is sent out and there is no response, wait 24hr and then send another one until three messages have been sent out, then stop sending the messages. Another example might be to send a message via one channel (e.g. email) and if there is no response then send to the alternative channel, and if there is no response then stop sending messages.

Comment: You start with "Most design patterns...". Often toasts are not designed to have interaction with. What are the patterns you mean, care to add some examples?

Comment: Before mobile apps the predominant design patterns were things like modals, dialog windows, validations and system notifications. I guess mobile apps have influenced that to a large extent so it's good that you are pointing this out. I have added a reference to desktop applications in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The closest example I can think of are to do with session timeouts, and there are some examples of this on government website design patterns such as GOV.UK.

Specifically, under the section for [Manage a session timeout](https://design-system.dwp.gov.uk/patterns/manage-a-session-timeout):

> **When to use this pattern** A service with sessions will normally end a session automatically after a certain amount of time if the user
> takes no action. If your service has an automatic timeout you should
> use this pattern to warn users and allow them to extend the session if
> they want to.
>
> You should warn a user at least 2 minutes before the end of this time.
> This will give them time to decide if they want to keep using the
> service.
>
> **How it works** Show the user the timeout warning at least 2 minutes before the time runs out. This should be shown to the user in a modal
> dialog, also known as a pop-up.
>
> The user can:
>
> - select a button to stay in the service and not time out press the    escape key to close the warning, stay in the service and not time out
> - do nothing
>
> If the user does nothing within the time limit, redirect them to a
> timeout page. This page explains what has happened and gives them
> options for how to continue.